# Angular IDE code completion

Tags: eclipse, angular, code-completion

Hi I am trying to use Angular IDE by webclipse to make an angular project but when I want to import something This IDE doesn't show any suggest, and it figures out only "No Default Proposal".

If I make a new project it works and show all the possible imports.

[image]